# Implicitly passing parameter to base constructor

Tags: c#, constructor

I have a class which looks like:

```
public class WidgetDao : AbstractDao<Widget>, IWidgetDao
{
    public WidgetDao(ISession session)
        : base (session)
    {

    }
}
```

My code has build errors if I attempt to remove this constructor on code which looks like:

```
public IWidgetDao GetWidgetDao()
{
    return _widgetDao ?? (_widgetDao = new WidgetDao(_session));
}
```

I sort of understand the reason why I get a build error... there's no explicit `WidgetDao` constructor which takes one parameter. However, `WidgetDao` inherits from `AbstractDao<Widget>` which does have a constructor which takes one parameter.

I don't understand why the C# compiler would make an explicit constructor required on `WidgetDao` when all it's used for is pass-through of the parameter to a base class.

Could someone shed some light on this for me?

Comment: "I don't understand why the C# compiler would make an explicit constructor required on WidgetDao when all it's used for is pass-through of the parameter to a base class." Because constructors aren't inherited, basically... and there are good reasons why they're *not* inherited... otherwise every class would end up with a parameterless constructor because `object` has a parameterless constructor, for example. Basically, don't try to remove that constructor.

Comment: That's fair enough. I just get a little suspicious of my code when I have almost empty constructors everywhere. Thanks for the response. Feel free to submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to automate this.  The only implicit constructor that C# will give your object is the default parameterless constructor, and it only does that if there are no alternatives in your code.  I'll build on this in a moment, but just for the foundation information...

Implicit `MyClass()` constructor:

```
public class MyClass 
{
}
```

In the above case, the compiler assumed you wanted a public parameterless constructor that didn't really do anything other than allow you to create an object.  You can call `new MyClass()` all day long even though you didn't create a constructor.

Now, what happens when you create your own constructor?

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

In this case, that implicit parameterless constructor still exists, but now it's private.  That means you cannot call `new MyClass()` any longer and you are required to provide a name.

Now let's make our class an abstract base class:

```
public abstract class AbstractMyClass
{
    protected AbstractMyClass(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public abstract void DoSomething();
}
```

There's no way to instantiate an abstract class, so it's a best practice to make your constructors `protected`.  Even if you made them `public` you couldn't access them directly anyway.  The important thing is that the same caveat holds: the default parameterless constructor is now private.  Any class that implements this base class must provide a value for `name` or the class is not fully instantiated.

```
public class SeansClass
{
    public SeansClass() : base("Sean") { }

    public void DoSomething() { }
}
```

In this case, we re-introduced the standard parameterless constructor and had it provide the `name` for our class.  This is perfectly valid code.  *The only caveat is that the value provided in the `base()` call must be a **compile time constant** or **calculated from the parameter** passed in to your class.*  The `base()` method is always evaluated first.

There is no way for C# to make the assumption that you in fact want all implementations of a base class to have the same constructor.  Each class may add constructors or provide their own values for the base class.  This is merely a limitation of C#.