# Implicitly passing parameter(s) to base constructor C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, base-class

I'm interested in the exact same question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37282912/implicitly-passing-parameter-to-base-constructor),
but for C++. Is there any way to **implicitly** pass parameters
to a **base class constructor**? Here is a small example I've tried
which doesn't work. When I remove the comments and **call the base
class constructor explicitly**, everything works fine.

```
struct Time { int day; int month; };
class Base {
public:
    Time time;
    Base(Time *in_time)
    {
        time.day   = in_time->day;
        time.month = in_time->month;
    }
};
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    int hour;
    // Derived(Time *t) : Base(t) {}
};
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Time t = {30,7};
    Derived d(&t);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the complete compilation line + compilation error if it helps:

```
$ g++ -o main main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:19:14: error: no matching function for call to ‘Derived::Derived(Time*)’
  Derived d(&t);
              ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bring all base class constructors into the scope of the subclass like this

```
class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    using Base::Base;

  /* ... */
};
```

which allows for exactly the usage scenario

```
Time t = {30,7};
Derived d(&t);
```

Note that `using Base::Base` always ships *all* constructors declared by `Base`. There is no way of omitting one or more.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by pulling in the `Base` class constructors into the scope of the `Derived` class:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    using Base::Base;  // Pull in the Base constructors

    // Rest of class...
};
```

---

On an unrelated note, I really recommend against using pointers. In this case it's simply not needed at all. Pass by value instead. That will make your `Base` constructor even simpler:

```
Base(Time in_time)
    : time(in_time)
{}
```

Comment: Clearly +1 as posted 7 seconds earlier :)